# How to customize pubDate from external RSS feed

Tags: php, rss, pubdate

I'm trying to fetch the pubDate from an RSS feed from an external page.

so far i have:

```
$result .= '<span><h3><a href="'.$entry->link.'" title="'.$entry->title.'">'.$entry->title.'</a></h3><p>'.$entry->pubDate.'</p></span>';
```

which gives me the result:

```
Mon, 23 Sep 2013 01:20:04 +0000
```

How do i make it `Monday, 23/09/2013 01:20:04`?

Comment: Please tag with a language tag

Comment: @laalto: language tag?

Comment: Yes, edit the question and include the language you're working in in the tags section (where you now have "rss" and "pubdate").

Comment: ah ok :-) PHP is the language... i added it to the tags, as you said :-)